# whatsapp-web.js, how do I send someone a contact card of someone else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

How do I send someone a contact card of someone else in whatsapp-web.js?
Can I send a contact card when
The person I send the contact card is saved on my phone but the contact I want to send is not on the contact list on my phone

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('ready', async () => {   try {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
    const saved = [];

    var array = fs.readFileSync('numb.txt').toString().split("\n"); //reading file
    for (i in array) {
      //console.log(array[i]);
      saved.push(array[i].substring(1)); //array with number 
    }

    const contacts = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < saved.length; i++) {
      contacts.push(await client.getContactById(saved[i] + '@c.us')); }
    client.sendMessage(to, contacts); //sending contact cards   
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send it by sending vcard as text message.

Example:

```
client.on('ready', async () => {
    client.sendMessage(
        '1234567890@c.us', 
        'BEGIN:VCARD
          ....(vcarddata)....
        END:VCARD', 
        {'parseVCards':true}) // by default its true
     .then(...).catch(...);
});
```

VCard will be parsed and made contact by parseVCard option.